# Custom Woocommerce create_order api modification

Tags: wordpress, api, woocommerce, customization, edit

I have created a custom create_order() api function in wordpress woocommerce. but i realize it only take in singular product which is not dynamically. currently if i have a product id 1 ~ 5 (single product) 6 to 10 are variable products,this code will only add one product each time.

how do I change my code so that it will be able to add **MULTIPLE** different kinds/groups of products? whether or not it is a single product or variable product or bundle products into 1 Order?

Sorry for my bad English :)

```
public function create_order()
        {
            if ($_REQUEST['dev']) {
                $address = array(
                'first_name' => 'Zayle',
                'last_name' => 'Ong',
                'company' => 'Timios',
                'email' => 'Crystalizewy@hotmail.com',
                'phone' => '777-777-777-777',
                'address_1' => '31 Main Street',
                'address_2' => '',
                'city' => 'Simei',
                'state' => 'SG',
                'postcode' => '520151',
                'country' => 'Singapore'
                );
                $userid = 1;
                $productid = 196; // put here an id of a product that is available on Woocommerce->Products
                $pointstouse = 100;
                } else {
                $address = array(
                'first_name' => $_POST['first_name'],
                'last_name' => $_POST['last_name'],
                'company' => $_POST['company'],
                'email' => $_POST['email'],
                'phone' => $_POST['phone'],
                'address_1' => $_POST['adddress1'],
                'address_2' => $_POST['adddress2'],
                'city' => $_POST['city'],
                'state' => $_POST['state'],
                'postcode' => $_POST['postcode'],
                'country' => $_POST['country']
                );
                $userid = $_POST['userid'];
                $productid = $_POST['productidid'];
                $pointstouse = $_POST['pointstouse'];
                if (! $_POST['first_name'] && ! $_POST['last_name'] && ! $_POST['email'] && ! $_POST['adddress1'] & ! $_POST['city']) {
                    return array(
                    "error" => "Please fill First name, Last Name, Address and City",
                    "orderstatus" => "error"
                    );
                }
                if (!$userid) {
                    return array(
                    "error" => "Need to specify a userid",
                    "orderstatus" => "error"
                    );
                }
                if (!$productid) {
                    return array(
                    "error" => "Need to specify a product id",
                    "orderstatus" => "error"
                    );
                }
                if (!$pointstouse) {
                    return array(
                    "error" => "Need to specify points to use",
                    "orderstatus" => "error"
                    );
                }
            }
            $pointsuser = WC_Points_Rewards_Manager::get_users_points($userid);
            if ($pointsuser >= $pointstouse) {
                $order = wc_create_order();
                $product = new WC_Product($productid);
                if (!$product->is_type('variable')) {
                    update_post_meta($productid, "_stock", (get_post_meta($productid, "_stock", true) - 1));
                    }else{

                }
                $order->add_product($product, 1);
                $order->set_address($address, 'billing');
                $order->set_address($address, 'shipping');
                $discount_code = str_replace("--userid--", $userid, "wc_points_redemption_--userid--_" . date("d-m-Y") . "_" . rand(0, 99999));
                /*
                    * Create coupon
                */
                $coupon_code = $discount_code; // Code
                $amount = WC_Points_Rewards_Manager::calculate_points_value($pointstouse); // Amount
                $discount_type = 'fixed_cart'; // Type: fixed_cart, percent, fixed_product, percent_product

                $coupon = array(
                'post_title' => $coupon_code,
                'post_content' => '',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_author' => 1,
                'post_type' => 'shop_coupon'
                );

                $new_coupon_id = wp_insert_post($coupon);

                // Add meta
                update_post_meta($new_coupon_id, 'discount_type', $discount_type);
                update_post_meta($new_coupon_id, 'coupon_amount', $amount);
                update_post_meta($new_coupon_id, 'individual_use', 'no');
                update_post_meta($new_coupon_id, 'product_ids', '');
                update_post_meta($new_coupon_id, 'exclude_product_ids', '');
                update_post_meta($new_coupon_id, 'usage_limit', '1');
                update_post_meta($new_coupon_id, 'expiry_date', '');
                update_post_meta($new_coupon_id, 'apply_before_tax', 'yes');
                update_post_meta($new_coupon_id, 'free_shipping', 'no');
                $order->add_coupon($discount_code, $amount);
                $order->calculate_totals();
                $order->set_total($order->calculate_totals() - $amount);
                $order->set_total($amount, 'cart_discount');
                $orderid = new WC_Order($order->ID);
                $order_id = trim(str_replace('#', '', $order->get_order_number()));

                add_post_meta($order_id, '_payment_method', 'cheque');
                update_post_meta($order_id, '_created_via', 'checkout');
                update_post_meta($order_id, '_customer_user', $userid);
                add_post_meta($order_id, '_payment_method_title', 'Cheque Payment');
                update_post_meta($order->id, '_wc_points_redeemed', $pointstouse);
                WC_Points_Rewards_Manager::decrease_points($userid, $pointstouse, 'order', "coupon " . $coupon_code . " used for order " . $order_id, $order_id);
                return array(
                "orderid" => $order_id,
                "orderstatus" => "ok"
                );
                } else {
                return array(
                "error" => "You do not have enought points",
                "orderstatus" => "error"
                );
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved

```
$order = wc_create_order();
                if (count($products)) {
                    foreach ($products as $key => $value) {
                        if ($value['variation']) {
                            $product = new WC_Product_Variable($value['id']);
                            $product->variation_id = $value['variation'];
                            $variation = $product->get_available_variations();
                            foreach ($variation as $key2 => $value2) {
                                if ($value2['variation_id'] == $value['variation']) {
                                    $valdata['variation'] = $value2['attributes'];
                                }
                            }
                            $order->add_product($product, $value['quantity'], $valdata);
                            update_post_meta($value['variation'], "_stock", (get_post_meta($productid, "_stock", true) - $value['quantity']));
                            } else {
                            $product = new WC_Product($value['id']);
                            $order->add_product($product, $value['quantity']);
                            update_post_meta($value['id'], "_stock", (get_post_meta($productid, "_stock", true) - $value['quantity']));
                        }
                    }
                }
```